# Prisma findMany where relationship is not null

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, prisma

I have these two low-end models and I want to list all their subcategories with their menus, provided that the menu is not empty.

```
model SubCategory {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  label      String
  image      String
  categories Category[] @relation("CategoryToSubCategory")
  menu       Menu[]     @relation("MenuToSubCategory")
  createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime   @updatedAt
}

model Menu {
  id                     Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                   String                  @db.VarChar(64)
  description            String                  @db.Text
  favoriteMenus          FavoriteMenus[]
  ingredients            Ingredients[]
  createdAt              DateTime                @default(now())
  updatedAt              DateTime                @updatedAt

  @@index([chefStoreId], map: "Menu_chefStoreId_fkey")
  @@fulltext([name, description])
}
```

The query I am writing is as follows:

```js
const topCategories = await this.prisma.subCategory.findMany({
  include: {
    menu: {
      where: {
        id: { not: null },
      },
    },
  },
  orderBy: {
    id: 'desc',
  },
  take: 50,
});
```

But it gives me the error `"Argument` not `must not be null."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, `menu` won't ever be null because it's an array, it will be just an empty array. `Menu` id also can't be null in your schema.

But if you mean that you want to find `subCategory` which has at least 1 menu attached, then I think you need to use `some` relation filter with empty params ([docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#remarks-24)):

```
  const topCategories = this.prisma.subCategory.findMany({
    where: {
      menu: {
        some: {},
      },
    },
    include: {
      menu: true,
    },
    orderBy: {
      id: 'desc',
    },
    take: 50,
  });
```